# A question about Brooks' theorem on graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Brooks' theorem in graph theory states that:

> **BROOKS' THEOREM.** If the valencies of all vertices $x$ of a graph $G$ satisfies
>   the condition $v(x)\leq s$ where $s\geq 3$, and $G$ does not contain a complete
>   $(s + 1)$-graph, then the chromatic number of $G$ is not more than $s$.

My question is on criterion ''*$G$ does not contain a complete
$(s + 1)$-graph*''. Does this possible? i.e. A graph $G$ such that $v(x)\leq s$ contain a complete
$(s + 1)$-graph.

Comment: Doesn't the complete graph on $s + 1$ vertices satisfy this condition?

Comment: ahh. Yes. you are right. Except complete graph, does exist such graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more general case of a graph $G$ with $\Delta(G)\le s$ containing a complete graph $K_{s+1}$ is when $G$ has a copy of $K_{s+1}$ as one of its connected components.

That's as general as you get: usually the theorem is stated for connected graphs, in which case $K_{s+1}$ (or, for $s=2$, any odd cycle) is the only counterexample.